# How can I transfer photos and files from Nokia 2760?

Tags: bluetooth, file-transfer

I need to transfer files from an old Nokia 2760 to another device.

I connect the phone via Bluetooth with a notebook and an Android smartphone, but I have not find the solution.

Many of these photo were sent to the Nokia 2760 via Bluetooth years ago from another Nokia.

With the notebook I am able to navigate to the folders of the cell phone, and I am able to open the photos, but I am not able to copy any photo. It gives me this error: `Another operation in progress`

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in more recent versions of Ubuntu.  In older versions, I was able to transfer files smoothly.

Bug report:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bluez/+bug/1284308